# Combining columns in attribute table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, concatenation, column

How can I merge columns in attribute table with / as delimeters?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the field calculator then use the formula:

```
"column1" || '/' || "column2"
```

Answer (score 4):

Also you may use the combination of [`array_to_string()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#array-to-string), [`map_avals()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#map-avals), and [`attributes()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#attributes) to get **all attributes** concatenated with *a comma*:

```
array_to_string(map_avals(attributes()))
```